# Make hidden folders invisible sftp

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, sftp, amazon-ec2, file-attributes

My client needed sftp server for sharing files, so I created sftp server on a amazon ec2 ubuntu machine and added different users.

Now their need is when user login to sftp server either via winscp or some other client, they should be able to see only their own folders in home directory, the other folders should not be visible to them. Also in their home directories they should not see any files or folder which start with dot(.).

Is this possible? e.g. see screenshot link below, I just want my client to see/access Transcript folder, nothing else.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kEHfW.png]

Comment: Is `zmed` the user you added for the client, or your own user ID?  Giving them access somewhere else than `/home` is probably the simplest workaround (i.e. create a dedicated directory for transfers in `/var/ftp` or wherever).

Comment: Same question at http://serverfault.com/questions/640800/make-hidden-folders-invisible-sftp

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thanks everyone, finally this link helped me to achieve my task. http://rmtheis.wordpress.com/2011/07/03/setting-up-an-sftp-site-on-amazon-web-services-ec2-creating-an-account-to-share-with-a-third-party-and-restricting-that-account-to-allow-only-sftp/

> This consists of three parts:
>
> - setting up an sftp site on EC2
> - creating a new user account
> - configuring the new user account to do read-only ftp, with no ssh privileges
>
> *This is intended for transferring files to and from trusted users. I
>   use this as an adequate solution for occasionally sending very large
>   files to clients, using an EC2 instance dedicated to that task. After
>   the transfer is complete, I shut down or delete the instance.*
>
> Set up a server using Amazon Web Services EC2, choosing an Ubuntu
>   Amazon Machine Image (AMI). (You can find an AMI using
>   http://cloud.ubuntu.com/ami/. You may want to choose one that’s free
>   tier eligible, such as ami-1aad5273)
>
> ssh into the server:
>
> `ssh -i keyfile.pem ubuntu@ec2-hostname.amazonaws.com`
>
> Install vsftpd:
>
> `sudo apt-get install vsftpd`
>
> Create a new user:
>
> `sudo adduser newusername`
>
> Using the AWS Management Console, generate a new key pair for the
>   third-party user.
>
> Using puttygen, import the new key (keyname.pem) and copy its public
>   key.
>
> On the server, create the .ssh directory for the new user:
>
> `sudo mkdir /home/newusername/.ssh`
>
> Paste the public key into `/home/newusername/.ssh/authorized_keys`.
>
> Set permissions:
>
> `sudo chmod 700 /home/newusername/.ssh`
>
> `sudo chmod 600 /home/newusername/.ssh/authorized_keys`
>
> `sudo chown -R newusername:newusername /home/newusername/.ssh`
>
> Test the new user’s sftp login from your local machine:
>
> `sftp -o IdentityFile=newkeypair1.pem`
>   `newusername@ec2-hostname.amazonaws.com`
>
> Make a new group for users who should be limited to using only sftp:
>
> `sudo groupadd sftponly`
>
> `sudo adduser newusername sftponly`
>
> Edit `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` and change the Subsystem line to:
>
> `Subsystem sftp internal-sftp`
>
> and add these lines to the end of `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`:
>
> `Match group sftponly`
>   `ChrootDirectory /home/%u`
>   `X11Forwarding no`
>   `AllowTcpForwarding no`
>   `ForceCommand internal-sftp`
>
> Set permissions, without clobbering files necessary for EC2’s
>   key-based authentication:
>
> `sudo chown root:root /home/newusername`
>
> `sudo chown -R newusername:newusername /home/newusername/.ssh`
>
> `sudo /etc/init.d/ssh restart`
>
> Now the new user can connect by sftp, but not by ssh. Place the files
>   you want to share in `/home/newusername`, and share the key with the
>   user.

Comment: Could you please share with us, here, the solution for you question ?

Comment: The solution is exactly what's there in the link. http://rmtheis.wordpress.com/2011/07/03/setting-up-an-sftp-site-on-amazon-web-services-ec2-creating-an-account-to-share-with-a-third-party-and-restricting-that-account-to-allow-only-sftp/

Comment: sorry for not being clear on this one: providing only a link to a website is not considered a good answer generally on stackexchange websites: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers, http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92505/should-i-flag-answers-which-contain-only-a-link-as-not-an-answer .

Comment: Alright from next time I would post answer also along with link.

Comment: it's not answering the question